# How to extract all the hrefs and titles from several `<a href="" title=""> tags?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Given this [file](https://pastebin.com/Gh6CCA0T):

```
<a data-parent="#accordion1" data-toggle="collapse" href="# fruitName1" title="Click to expand drug name">
<span class="list-unstyled" style="text-decoration: none;"></span> GLIPIZIDE 
         </a>
<a href="/loads/data/usersindex.cfm?event=overview.subprocess&amp;ApplNo=114223" title="Click to view LEMONS (LEMONS) | POQ  #114223 | BOX;67 PZ | PRESENTATION | FRUIT COMPANY 1 ">
                              LEMONS (LEMONS)</a>
<a href="/loads/data/usersindex.cfm?event=overview.subprocess&amp;ApplNo=114226" title="Click to view LEMONS (LEMONS) | POQ  #114226 | BOX;67 PZ | PRESENTATION | FRUIT COMPANY 2 ">
                              LEMONS (LEMONS)</a>
<a href="/loads/data/usersindex.cfm?event=overview.subprocess&amp;ApplNo=114305" title="Click to view LEMONS (LEMONS) | POQ  #114305 | BOX;67 PZ | PRESENTATION | FRUIT COMPANY 3 ">
                              LEMONS (LEMONS)</a>
<a href="/loads/data/usersindex.cfm?event=overview.subprocess&amp;ApplNo=114370" title="Click to view LEMONS (LEMONS) | POQ  #114370 | BOX;67 PZ | Discontinued | FRUIT COMPANY 1 ">
                              LEMONS (LEMONS)</a>
<a href="/loads/data/usersindex.cfm?event=overview.subprocess&amp;ApplNo=114378" title="Click to view LEMONS (LEMONS) | POQ  #114378 | BOX;67 PZ | Discontinued | FRUIT COMPANY 4 ">
                              LEMONS (LEMONS)</a>
<a href="/loads/data/usersindex.cfm?event=overview.subprocess&amp;ApplNo=114387" title="Click to view LEMONS (LEMONS) | POQ  #114387 | BOX;67 PZ | Discontinued | FRUIT COMPANY 5 ">
                              LEMONS (LEMONS)</a>
<a href="/loads/data/usersindex.cfm?event=overview.subprocess&amp;ApplNo=114438" title="Click to view LEMONS (LEMONS) | POQ  #114438 | BOX;67 PZ | PRESENTATION | FRUIT COMPANY 2 ">
                              LEMONS (LEMONS)</a>
<a href="/loads/data/usersindex.cfm?event=overview.subprocess&amp;ApplNo=114497" title="Click to view LEMONS (LEMONS) | POQ  #114497 | BOX;67 PZ | PRESENTATION | FRUIT COMPANY 5 ">
                              LEMONS (LEMONS)</a>
<a href="/loads/data/usersindex.cfm?event=overview.subprocess&amp;ApplNo=114542" title="Click to view LEMONS (LEMONS) | POQ  #114542 | BOX;67 PZ | Discontinued | FRUIT COMPANY 3 ">
                              LEMONS (LEMONS)</a>
<a href="/loads/data/usersindex.cfm?event=overview.subprocess&amp;ApplNo=114550" title="Click to view LEMONS (LEMONS) | POQ  #114550 | 
         </a>
<a href="/loads/data/usersindex.cfm?event=overview.subprocess&amp;ApplNo=117270" title="Click to view GRAPES (GREEN GRAPES ; AUS) | POQ  #117270 | BOX;67 PZ | PRESENTATION | FRUIT COMPANY 10  ">
                              GRAPES (GREEN GRAPES ; AUS)</a>
<a href="/loads/data/usersindex.cfm?event=overview.subprocess&amp;ApplNo=117511" title="Click to view GRAPES (GREEN GRAPES ; AUS) | POQ  #117511 | BOX;67 PZ | PRESENTATION | FRUIT COMPANY 11 ">
                              GRAPES (GREEN GRAPES ; AUS)</a>
<a href="/loads/data/usersindex.cfm?event=overview.subprocess&amp;ApplNo=117620" title="Click to view GRAPES (GREEN GRAPES ; AUS) | POQ  #117620 | BOX;67 PZ | PRESENTATION | FRUIT COMPANY 12 ">
```

Using a regex or beautiful soup, how to extract all the `<a href="" title="">`, adding `www.example.com` before the `href` tags into:

```
www.example.com/loads/data/usersindex.cfm?event=overview.subprocess&amp;ApplNo=114223 |  title= | Click to view LEMONS (LEMONS) | POQ  #114223 | BOX;67 PZ | PRESENTATION | FRUIT COMPANY 1 | LEMONS (LEMONS)
www.example.com/loads/data/usersindex.cfm?event=overview.subprocess&amp;ApplNo=114226 |  title= | Click to view LEMONS (LEMONS) | POQ  #114226 | BOX;67 PZ | PRESENTATION | FRUIT COMPANY 2 | LEMONS (LEMONS)
www.example.com/loads/data/usersindex.cfm?event=overview.subprocess&amp;ApplNo=114305 |  title= | Click to view LEMONS (LEMONS) | POQ  #114305 | BOX;67 PZ | PRESENTATION | FRUIT COMPANY 3 | LEMONS (LEMONS)
www.example.com/loads/data/usersindex.cfm?event=overview.subprocess&amp;ApplNo=114370 |  title= | Click to view LEMONS (LEMONS) | POQ  #114370 | BOX;67 PZ | Discontinued | FRUIT COMPANY 1 | LEMONS (LEMONS)
```

I tried to:

```
for a in soup.tbody.findAll('a', href=True):
    r = re.compile('(?<=href=").*?(?=")')
    r.findall(str(a)
```

And:

```
for a in soup.tbody.findAll('a', href=True):
    print (a.find('a')['href'])
    print (a.find('a')['title'])
```

However, I do not get how to rearrange the titles and the hrefs.
**UPDATE**

Based on odradek's answer, I tried this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open('file.htm'), 'lxml')
for a in soup.tbody.findAll('a', href=True):
    html = a
    PREFIX = 'www.example.com'
    template = '{prefix}{url} | {title}'.format
    links = [template(prefix=PREFIX, url=e['href'], title=e['title']) for e in html.find_all('a', href=True)]
    print(links)
```

However I got:

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use BeautifulSoup parsing methods instead of complicated regexp for this:

```
# this is the url you want to add at the beginning
PREFIX = 'www.example.com'

# the template of your desired output
template = '{prefix}{url} | {title}'.format

# the resulting list, please note that "html" variable is
# the given source code.
links = [template(prefix=PREFIX, url=e.get('href'), title=e.get('title'))
         for e in html.find_all('a', href=True)]
```

when ran against two `a` tags of your list:

```
$ python get_all_a.py
www.example.com/loads/data/usersindex.cfm?event=overview.subprocess&ApplNo=117511 | Click to view GRAPES (GREEN GRAPES ; AUS) | POQ  #117511 | BOX;67 PZ | PRESENTATION | FRUIT COMPANY 11 
www.example.com/loads/data/usersindex.cfm?event=overview.subprocess&ApplNo=117620 | Click to view GRAPES (GREEN GRAPES ; AUS) | POQ  #117620 | BOX;67 PZ | PRESENTATION | FRUIT COMPANY 12
```

based on your update, you shouldn't put this piece of code inside that for loop, rather:

```
html = BeautifulSoup(open('file.htm'), 'html.parser')

PREFIX = 'www.example.com'

template = '{prefix}{url} | {title}'.format

# inside this list comprehension is your for loop implied
links = [template(prefix=PREFIX, url=e.get('href'), title=e.get('title'))
         for e in html.find_all('a', href=True)]
```

Comment: I tried to `soup = BeautifulSoup(open('/file.htm'), 'lxml')
PREFIX = 'www.example.com'
template = '{prefix}{url} | {title}'.format
links = [template(prefix=PREFIX, url=e['href'], title=e['title'])
         for e in html.find_all('a', href=True)]
print(links)` and got an empty list: `[]`

Comment: that's not exactly my code. you are using `lxml` parser while i'm using `html.parser`. also, you are loading the `bs4.BeautifulSoup` object into the `soup` variable while iterating over `html` in the list comprehension.

Comment: Sorry... I tried gain with the above code and got: `---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-cf84682c681c> in <module>()
      9 # inside this list comprehension is your for loop implied
     10 links = [template(prefix=PREFIX, url=e['href'], title=e['title'])
---> 11          for e in html.find_all('a', href=True)]`

Comment: ok, i updated the code so it doesn't fail with KeyError, but i think there's something wrong with the source code you're loading. either you're loading another file (be careful with the leading `/` in `open(/file.htm)`, which indicates the root directory if you're using linux), or the file loaded doesn't contain that code sample. i've just run my code against all the `a` tags you posted (included in a file called `file.htm` and it works smoothly.

Comment: Thanks for the help and for your patience!.. I will check it!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't task for regexp. You can use BeautifulSoup as presented in odradek's answer or there is my favorite alternative `lxml`, which in my opinion leads to more readable code:

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.fromstring(html)
for element in tree.xpath('//a'):
    print('www.example.com' + element.get('href'))
    print('title: ' + element.get('title'))
```

Comment: To parse from file use `etree.parse('../file.htm')` instead of `etree.fromstring(html)`.

Comment: Thanks for the help!... instead of printing them how can I append them into a single list?

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark one of the answers as solution. If you have another problem, you can ask a new question. However I strongly recommend to go through some basic tutorials at first. (Hint: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm)

Comment: THanks for the reference